# Change HTML tag styles with GREP in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, html, character-styles, grep

I have some HTML in a text and I would like to apply a character style to the HTML tags:

```
<p>This is some <strong>HTML</strong> I want to use.</p>
```

I want to only change the *tag name*, not the `<` or `>`. In other words, I want to change the style of the `p` but not the enclosing `<>`.

Normally, I would use: `\<(.*?)\>` to capture the group inside the brackets, but InDesign includes the brackets!

Answer (score 4):

Its not a good idea to [parse *HTML*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1335032) with regular expressions (GREP). ;(

Why are you esscaping the `<` and `>` chars? they should have no specific meaning in regular expressions. Try `<(.*?)>` or even better `<([^<>]*)>`. But that matches the entire thing tough it has a matching group, you can use it to replace, but it does not alter the selection. So what you need is something different.

#### Look ahead and look behind operator

You can find them under the match group. In this case they are positive look ahead/behind objects. What this does is it matches if these things surround the match So your regexp becomes:

```
(?<=<)([^<>]*)(?=>)
```

There exits also something called negative lookaheads/behinds that matches if match is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was working, but character styles were overriding paragraph styles. :(

FWIW, [joojaa](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/18306/joojaa) is right that the `<` and `>` don't need to be escaped, and his regex is probably a lot more robust.